# What's the reason for a battery light coming on and becoming brighter as the engine revs higher?

Tags: electrical, battery, warning-light

The vehicle is a 1993 LandRover Discovery 3.5 V8.   Today when I hopped in to drive home the battery light came on when I started up, and remained on.  It gets brighter as the engine revs and just about extinguishes at idle.

The battery seems fine.  No problem cranking.  Electolyte fine.  Battery voltage at rest is 13.6v, rising to over 15 when the engine revs.  All belts are OK.

Is this a regulator problem?  Am I in danger of frying the battery if I drive it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost certainly the voltage regulator.  Potentially could damage the battery eventually, but you're most likely to damage sensitive electronics in the car first.  If the voltage gets high enough, the wiring insulation may not be able to handle it too.  Not sure what voltage typical automotive wiring is certified for.  This is something you should repair immediately.